# Error de comparacion de datos en base de datos

Tags: mysql, python

Al intentar  `logearme` con  usuario y clave de una base de datos propia,  no hace la comparación correcta en el `if` y se salta a la condición `else`.

**Código**

```
import mysql.connector
import sys
from Tkinter import *
dato={
"user":"root",
"password":"",
"database":"baseusuarios",
"host":"127.0.0.1"
}
conexion=mysql.connector.connect(** dato)
cursor=conexion.cursor(buffered=True)

def Usuario():
ventUsuario=Tk()
ventUsuario.geometry("250x200+500+120")
ventUsuario.title("Sistema")
Usu=Label(ventUsuario,text="Usuario:",font=("Agency FB",14)).place(x=5,y=10)
cajaU=Entry(ventUsuario)
cajaU.place(x=100,y=20)
Contrasena=Label(ventUsuario,text="Contraseña:",font=("Agency FB",14)).place(x=5,y=50)
cajaC=Entry(ventUsuario,show="*")
cajaC.place(x=100,y=60)
botonU=Button(ventUsuario,text="Ingresar",command=lambda:ingresar(cajaU,cajaC))
botonU.place(x=100,y=100)
botonA=Button(ventUsuario,text="Crear una cuenta",command=lambda:cuentas(ventUsuario))
botonA.place(x=75,y=150)
ventUsuario.mainloop()

def ingresar(cajaU,cajaC):
     Usuario=cajaU.get()
     Contra=cajaC.get()
     nom="hola"
     ventIngresar=Tk()
     ventIngresar.geometry("300x200+500+120")
     ventIngresar.title("Ingresando al Sistema")

     if(cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `usuarios` WHERE `nombre`='" + Usuario 
        + "' AND `contrasena`='"+ Contra +  "'")):
          var2nombre=Label(ventIngresar,text="Has ingresado correctamente al sistema",font=("Agency FB",14)).place(x=10,y=10)
     else: 
        varnombre=Label(ventIngresar,text="Usuario o Contraseña incorrecta",font=("Agency FB",14)).place(x=10,y=10)
     ventIngresar.mainloop()
```

Comment: Por favor, define cual lenguaje estas ocupando.

Comment: Seria en Python, es que no me dejo poner la etiqueta de python, gracias por la observación

Comment: No he utilizado mucho Python, ¿`.get()` sanea las entradas de usuario? Porque si no, creo que tu código puede ser vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL

Comment: Si, en una caja de texto se ingresan los datos y se extraen con .get()

Answer (score 1):

Hay varios errores en tu código:

El metodo .get() es para diccionarios, normalmente para dar valores concretos en el caso de que no encuetre la key que esta buscando. te dejo algunos ejemplos basicos de entrada - Salida:

```
>> dict = {'Nombre': 'Miguel', 'Age': 17}
>> dict.get('Nombre')
'Miguel'
>> dict['Nombre']
'Miguel'
>>dict.get('Uncampoquenoexiste')
(no devuelve nada)
>>> dict['Uncampoquenoexiste']
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 KeyError: 'Uncampoquenoexiste'
>> gict.get('Uncampoquenoexiste', 'ValorPorDefecto')
'ValorPorDefecto'
```

si lo haces sobre un STR, da error (que creo que es tu caso):

```
>>> cajaU = 'Miguel'
>>> cajaU.get()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Si tu ya estás pasando a la función los parametros correctos (el texto), simplemente puedes usar ese texto:

```
def ingresar(cajaU,cajaC):
     Usuario=cajaU
     Contra=cajaC
```

Si no es así, deberías indicarnos como y con que objetos estas llamando a esta función de ingresar.

Adicionalmente a este error. En el codigo que has pasado tienes un error de [SQL INJECTION](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

si tu campo contraseña introduzco:  ' or 1=1 me logrearé siempre con el primer usuario de la base de datos.
Hay que usar algo para limpiar los strings que introduzcas en consultas a bases de datos para evitar esto.

---

Para ver la query que está realizando haz un print de el literal que contiene el cursor.execute:*

print(("SELECT * FROM `usuarios` WHERE `nombre`='" + Usuario + "' AND `contrasena`='"+ Contra +  "'"))

Copia y pega eso que te ha dado en tu base de datos y comprueba que lo que está haciendo es correcto y que devuelve un usuario.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda mira la funcion ingresar la llamo desde este boton que esta dentro de la funcion usuario.

Comment: Hice pruebas para descartar que el error fuera producido por .get(). asi que dentro de la funcion ingresar puse dos variables: Usuario="miguel" y Contra="programa". en la base de datos puese este usurio y contraseña, pero sigue brincandose a la condicion else. Hice otroa prueba, En vez de este codigo "SELECT * FROM `usuarios` WHERE `nombre`'" + Usuario 
        + "' AND `contrasena`='"+ Contra +  "'" PUSE ESTE OTRO CODIGO "SELECT * FROM `usuarios` WHERE `nombre`LIKE'" + Usuario 
        + "' AND `contrasena`LIKE'"+ Contra +  "'"

Comment: Y una tercera prueba que hice fue poner  en las condiciones != en vez de =, con esto deberia de entrar por lo menos a la condicion if. ya que si el cliente escribe un usuario y contraseña diferente a la base de datos deberia de ingresar al if y no al else. pero tampoco dio resultado

Comment: No se que es lo que estas usando para generar los inputs, no lo he usado nunca.

Pero tu problema es que cuando haces el Caja.get() , te falta el parámetro del diccionario que contiene lo que tu buscas.

Si suponemos que cajaU y cajaC son objetos que tienen la propiedad .get() te falta el nombre de el atributo que deseas obtener.
por ejemplo cajaU.get('text')  Si no sabes donde ir a buscar te puedo apuntar 2 maneras Si es un diccionario: print(cajaU.keys) En el caso de que fuera un objeto: print(dir(cajaU))

Comment: Por seguridad, tambien comprueba que la query funciona bien, escribe el select con el usuario y la contraseña que no sean variables y comprueba que hace loggin

Comment: exactamente eso es lo que hice, puse un valor constantes igualito al usuario y contraseña de la base de datos, y no hace la comparacion bien. Al poner el .get() obtengo el valor de el Entry. cajaU=Entry(ventUsuario)  pero eso ya no importa si ponga una constante y de todos modos no hace la comparacion en mi base de datos

Comment: Entonces tu problema es otro. De que es instancia Cursor execute? Donde esta instanciado?

Comment: ya lo puse hasta arriba del código amigo. Gracias por la  ayuda

Comment: No acabo de ver el error. Haz una cosa, quita el cursor.execute() del if i lanza-lo, eso tiene que estar dando un error. Si lo ejecutas en terminal te dará el error, si no ponlo dentro de un try/ except y imprime el error que te esta dando.

Comment: Hice lo que me dijiste y el codigo me quedo asi: if("SELECT * FROM `usuarios` WHERE `nombre`='" + Usuario + "' AND `contrasena`='"+ Contra +  "'"): quitando el cursor.execute() y no me marco ningun error, y ahora siempre entra al if, y no hay forma de que entre al else, asi este totalmente difetente el usuario y contraseña comparados de la base.

Comment: no. Lo que tienes que quitar es el if, dejado la ejecución de el cursor.execute fuera de este, para que cuando de el error lo imprima por pantalla y no salte al else.

Comment: como puedo hacerlo que me dices, usando el try, es que ya lo  hice pero no me sale el error, entoces creoq eu se necesita usar el try pero no lo he manejado, soy relativamente nuevo en python

Comment: try: <codigo_tabulado>     except Exception as e:
        print(e)
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: Lo puse asi, y no me da error:   try:
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `usuarios` WHERE `nombre`='" + Usuario + "' &&`contrasena`='"+ Contra +  "'")
    except ValueError:
         print("Oops!  That was no valid number.  Try again...")